# Can I use variables from included files?

Tags: php

Is it possible to calculate percentage from values inside two included php files?

Something like that:

```
$percentage = (dash.php/dash1.php)*100;
echo $percentage
```

Where dash.php prints 1600 and dash1.php prints 1200.

dash.php:

```
$rezultat = "SELECT sum(vrednost) as vrednost FROM vrednosti WHERE username = '$username' AND cas between '".date("Y-m-01")."' AND '".date("Y-m-31 23:59:59")."' ";
$result = mysqli_query($link, $rezultat) or die (mysqli_error($link));

$sestevek = mysqli_fetch_object($result);

//This would normally print 1600
echo number_format($sestevek->vrednost, 2, ",", "");
```

Comment: What are 1600 & 1200? Are they sizes, or contained in the file or something?

Comment: dash.php is this month sumed values and than echoed, dash1.php is previous month...

Comment: So when you include dash.php, the result is that it echoes 1600? And by including dash1.php the result is echoing 1200?

Comment: can you edit your question to include some of the code from the file? It would be easier to explain if I can see the bit of code that echoes the number

Answer (score 2):

Instead of `echo number_format($sestevek->vrednost, 2, ",", "");` you want to assign it to a variable like so:

`$dash = number_format($sestevek->vrednost, 2, ",", "");`

Do the same in dash1.php but assign to something like dash1:

`$dash1 = number_format($sestevek->vrednost, 2, ",", "");`

Then in the file that includes dash and dash1:

```
include 'dash.php';
include 'dash1.php';
```

Now you can use your variables `$dash, $dash1` as if you were inside dash.php or dash1.php.

```
$percentage = ($dash/$dash1)*100;
```

**Having said that**:
I think you should look at putting the code into a function of some sort as including the files and using the variables could lead to clashes and confusion later on.  It would be much safer to code like this:

```
$dash = getDashValue();
$dash1 = getDash1Value();
```

Hope that makes sense :)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you wanted to do it from inside a third script (as opposed to doing it from the command line) you could call each script using the php [exec](http://php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php) function and then do what ever you needed with those results.